# XEN Debian Lenny

Tags: xen, kernel

Is is safe to install the XEN Kernel on a server with 12 GB RAM and a i7 Quadcore CPU?

```
MemTotal:     12462952 kB
```

The reason I'm asking is this.

```
Debian-50-lenny-32-minimal:/proc# uname -r
2.6.26-2-686-bigmem
```

Is a "bigmem kernel" necessary to adress the complete range of the 12 GB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bigmem = PAE which will allow you to use more then 4GB with 32-bit.

It's not the best idea but it should work.